# SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hey guys I have tried to convert this query into a pivot table and I have searched everywhere but can't seem to apply it.  The following is my code.

```
SELECT ClientPartner, ClientManager, WIPAmount 
FROM tblTranWIP
WHERE (WIPDate>={ts '2013-04-01 00:00:00'} 
AND WIPDate<{ts '2014-03-31 00:00:01'})AND TransTypeIndex=1 AND ContIndex<900000
```

The following screenshot shows my output.  I basically want to have Managers and Partners as the First Column and Row and then have WipAmount be in the middle as ClientPartners and Managers match id's  The screen shot shows it easier than I explain. The link is a screenshot, the system won't let me add embed images

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/rgmajf5zb/readthis.png]

Comment: Each client manager has a related wip amount with a partner.  Basically if Client Manager 46 and Client Partner 24639 have several wip amounts those need to be totaled in the resulting report...so I wouldn't want to show 46 - 24639 = 55.00 and again 46 - 24639 = 27.50...I want it to show 46 - 24639 = 82.59. And same for each fields that relate to wip amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one way I know of to get the information you are looking for, and that is to use a PIVOT:

```
SELECT pvt.*
FROM
(
  SELECT ClientPartner, ClientManager, WIPAmount FROM tblTranWIP
) AS tranwip
PIVOT
(
 SUM(WIPAmount) FOR ClientPartner IN ([46], [58], [177], [207])
) AS pvt
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c459d/15/0).

Comment: Brian, thanks, I actually tried this last night before viewing your answer and I got it to work, however how would I go about making this table dyanmic as it is impossible for me to add the individual clientpartners one by one...

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot here on stackoverflow, there are a lot of question (and answers) on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

this was a great help, upon reading many tutorials.  I came up with the following code for what I needed, which was a dynamic pivot as I don't know every single column code.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @columns TABLE (COL varchar(50))
declare @columnscsv varchar(MAX)

insert into @columns
select distinct ClientPartner from tblTranWip

select @columnscsv = COALESCE(@columnscsv + '],[','') + COL from @columns
set @columnscsv = '[' + @columnscsv + ']'

SET @sql = 'Select ClientManager ' + @columnscsv + ' FROM(SELECT ClientPartner, ClientManager, WipAmount FROM tblTranWip) a 
PIVOT (MAX(WipAmount) for ClientPartner in (' + @columnscsv + ')) AS PVT ORDER by ClientManager'

EXEC (@sql)
```